# How to get the file name when using Part to upload files with JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, jsf-2

I'm using the below code snippet to upload a file using JSF

```
 private Part uploadedFile;
 public Part getUploadedFile() {
    return uploadedFile;
}
public void setUploadedFile(Part uploadedFile) {
    this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
}
public void processFileUpload()
{


if(!(uploadedFile==null))
{
fileName = uploadedFile.getName();
System.out.println(fileName);
fileSize = uploadedFile.getSize();
fileContentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();

}
else { System.out.println("null");
```

My jsp code snippets is shown below

```
<h:form enctype = "multipart/form-data">

<h:outputLabel value="Select File:" style="color:white"/>
<h:inputFile id="fileUpload" label="File to upload" style="color:white"
value="#{actionBeanWorld.uploadedFile}" size="60" />

 <h:commandButton type = "submit" value = "Upload"
 action = "#{actionBeanWorld.processFileUpload}">
 </h:commandButton>
```

The filename generated using uploadedFile.getName() generates only the Part name j_id_jsp_903082837_1:fileUpload but I was wondering if there was a way to get the filename I actually uploaded? I already tried using uploadedFile.getSubmittedFileName(); and it threw a java.lang.AbstractMethod error. Please help!

Comment: When you get an exception please **always** include the stack trace to exclude ambiguity. The correct answer is in there.

Answer (score 0):

[AbstractMethodError thrown by javax.servlet.http.Part.getSubmittedFileName()](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-4008)

MyFaces Core Affects Version/s: 2.2.6, 2.2.8

Please provide full details of the JSF version , Implementation , Server on which you are testing you code.